# Multiple wxGLCanvas with OpenGL-wxPaintDC drawing combination

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-7, wxwidgets

I have an application with two classes extending wxGLCanvas and one extending wxWindow. They implement 3 types of possible visualization of the user objects. Only one of them is displayed at the same time. The two wxGLCanvas contain a combination of an OpenGL scene plus some text superposed using wxPaintDC. The wxWindow draws everything using wxBufferedPaintDC.

Problem 1: In some machines, when exchanging from one wxGLCanvas to the other one, during the first rendering of the scene a background image is displayed just until the first rendered image appears. This background image I found out that comes from the wxGLCanvas background.

Problem 2:In the same machines where problem 1 appears, when using the function wxClientDC.Blit, instead of taking the OpenGL scene with the superposed text it is taking the wxGLCanvas background image (same as problem 1) with the superposed text; so it is taking the canvas context excluding the OpenGL scene. In the other machines the result of the screenshot is correct.

INFO: When I select the wxWindow view, where all is drawn using wxBufferedPaintDC, the background image of both, problem 1 and 2, is updated to the frame displayed by the wxWindow. If I now switch between wxGLCanvases I will see the "flash" of the wxWindow view.

Code to take screenshot (Inside class extending wxGLCanvas):

```
wxClientDC lv_contexteVue(this);
int lv_largeurVue;
int lv_hauteurVue;

lv_contexteVue.GetSize(&lv_largeurVue,&lv_hauteurVue);

wxBitmap lv_vue(lv_largeurVue,lv_hauteurVue);

wxMemoryDC lv_contexteAux;

lv_contexteAux.SelectObject(lv_vue);
lv_contexteAux.Blit(0,0,lv_largeurVue,lv_hauteurVue,&lv_contexteVue,0,0);

lv_vue.SaveFile(wxString(er_cheminSauvegarde.c_str(),wxConvLibc,er_cheminSauvegarde.size()),wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP);

lv_contexteAux.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);
```

Code to display scene OpenGL followed by the overlayed text (Inside class extending wxGLCanvas):

```
wxPaintDC dc(this);
//dc.Clear();
dc.SetBackground(*wxBLACK);
dc.SetBackgroundMode(wxSOLID);
dc.SetTextBackground(*wxBLACK);
dc.SetTextForeground(*wxWHITE);

SetCurrent(mv_contexte);

if (!mv_estInitialise)
{
    initialiser();
    mv_estInitialise = true;
}

Evenement lv_demandeDessin(DEMANDE_AFFICHAGE_2DPLUS);
mp_controleur->traiterEvenement(lv_demandeDessin);

SwapBuffers();


//dc.ClearCache();
wxColour lv_couleurEspaceLibre = *wxWHITE;
dc.SetBrush(wxBrush(lv_couleurEspaceLibre));
dc.SetPen(wxPen(lv_couleurEspaceLibre, 1));
//Overlay Text 
wxSize screenSize = this->GetSize();
//dc.SetTextForeground(wxColour(240, 240, 240, 255));
wxFont font(8, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false);
dc.SetFont(font);
//dc.SetTextBackground(wxColour(0, 0, 0, 200));
string formated = ConstantesATLAS::FILIGRANE_PRE+Constantes::VERSION+Constantes::FILIGRANE_POS;
wxString mystring = wxString::FromAscii(formated.c_str());
//dc.DrawText(mystring,5,screenSize.GetY()-20);
dc.DrawText(mystring,5,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from wxWidgets forum to the same question posted here, all credit for them :)

https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=40288&e=0

Summary: do not mix OpenGL and wxPaintDC. To take screenshot of openGL with overlayed text there are two good posibilities:

1-Put the overlayed text with OpenGL, e.g. a superposed orthographic projection. Then take screenshot using the function glReadPixels().

2-If text is overlayed using the DC, to take screenshot, first ask OpenGL to return all the viewport in an array. Transform this array to wxImage, resuperpose the text in the image the same way it is superposed in the repaint event, use the dc.Blit function to copy the image.